# Codeigniter how to format < > to html entities

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, formatting

I'm stack with codeigniter,
while getting the array values from database, I'm sending it to the parser, which is showing the page with the array values, so the problem is html not showing 
How to do that:

```
< to &lt;
> to &gt;
```

The main problem is html not showing it as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is the way to go using native PHP, but you can also use Codeigniter's [`html_escape`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/common_functions.html) function, which looks like this:

```
function html_escape($var)
{
    if (is_array($var))
    {
        return array_map('html_escape', $var);
    }
    else
    {
        return htmlspecialchars($var, ENT_QUOTES, config_item('charset'));
    }
}
```

You can also pass in arrays and it will escape every item. This also works with your charset (which should be `UTF-8`). In PHP 5.4, the default encoding is `UTF-8`, but prior to that it is `ISO-8859-1`, which means you have to set all 3 arguments every time you call `htmlspecialchars` or you may end up with a mangled string if it has characters not in the default encoding:

```
$var = htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

So it's a nice shortcut, and it's always available (no need to load a helper).

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) PHP function.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the output in `htmlspecialchars();` function, for example:

```
print htmlspecialchars($content);
```

Comment: I dont really understand why I was not awarded the answer as I was actually the first to answer it?